# добавление maven

Tags: java, android-studio, maven

Как мне добавить *Maven* в свой проект?

Cкачал всё, что нужно, добавил в переменные среды, но в корне моего проекта в Android Studio ничего не появилось.

Comment: [посмотри](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruG0SkRildo&t=59s), может поможет.

Comment: у меня нет этого меню в начале, с выбором файла, у меня есть только выбор акивити

Comment: [Вот](https://devcolibri.com/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-maven/) хороший guide.